# I want my container/span fixe there position

Tags: html, article

I have a problem here is my website http://jsbin.com/cesorozu/3/edit
But when i want to create a new span for a new article like that 
http://jsbin.com/fobalilorogo/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Game Nxt Gen</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="Welcome to the new generation of gaming !" content="Site de la team-multigaming Game Nxt Gen">
<meta name="author" content="Psyko460">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span13 pagination-centered"><img src="img/Banniere%20site.png"</img></div>
  </div>



                <ul class="nav nav-tabs Center pull-bottom">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="membres.html">Membres</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="videos.html">Vidéos</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                </ul>

   <div class="span13 Contbg Center ContBorder toBottom">  

     <div class="spannews toLeft toRight toTop bordered spanbg">
       New article
     </div>

   <div class="spannews toLeft toRight toTop bordered spanbg">
      <header><h2><img src="img/logo%20gng%2050.png"</img>  Présentation</h2></header>
       <hr width="100%">
   <br> Bonjour et bienvenue sur le site de la communauté Game Nxt Gen.<br>Nous sommes une communauté de joueur multi-gaming, nous jouons à toutes sorte de jeux FPS, MMO, STR, MOBA, RPG etc.. <br>La plupart des membres se connaissent depuis plusieurs années.<br>Nous acceuillons tous le monde sur le mumble, un bon sens de l'humour est requis !<br>Une IRL à déjà était faite la plupart de la communauté était présente, nous referons surement ça à pendants les vacances scolaire !<br><div class="pagination-centered toTop"><img src="Fond%20Stream%20samedi2.jpg"width="55%"</img></div>
   </div>



   <div class="spandlogin toLeft toRight toTop bordered spanbg">
    login
   </div>

    <div class="spanmumbleviewer toLeft toRight toTop toBottom bordered spanbg">
    mumble viewer
   </div>   

   </div>
<div class="pagination-centered">
Contact : marvin.psyko@gmail.com. Thème, design et code réalisés par Psyko460 accompagné de Twitter Bootstrap. © 2014 GameNxtGen.fr. 
<br> Welcome to the new generation of gaming !
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The login span and the mumble viewer span goes down i don't know how to completely fixe the position of the two span and when I create a new article they will not goes down.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it this way

```
  <div class="spandlogin toLeft toRight toTop bordered spanbg">
    login
   </div>

   <div class="spannews toLeft toRight toTop bordered spanbg">
    New article
   </div>
```

Comment: That's working but badly because the second article stay in the right column but goes down very far like that http://jsbin.com/fobalilorogo/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my problem and those who want the fix there is it !
So i simply create new div in the css named : .col-left and .col-right

.col-left{
 float: left
}

.col-right{
 float: right
}

put the article in the appropriate div !